# Update row in DB by other unique value instead primary key using Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, web-services, dao

I'm writing REST web-service. I create the next Author entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "author")
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "authorId", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int authorId;

    @Column(name = "authorName", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "authorSurname")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "nationality")
    private String nationality;

    @Column(name = "age")
    private int age;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Book> bookList;

    public Author() {
    }

    public Author(int authorId, String name, String surname, String nationality, int age) {
        this.authorId = authorId;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.nationality = nationality;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

The `id` value in DB using like Primary Key just inside DB for references to other tables. And for identifying entities by URL (like `/rest/Author/{authorId}`) use other value - `authorId`. I'm also didn't use it in entity constructor. The DAO updateAuthor method look like:

```
public Author updateAuthor(Author author) {
    Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    session.update(author);
    transaction.commit();

    Author updated = (Author) session
            .createQuery("FROM Author WHERE authorId=" + author.getAuthorId())
            .uniqueResult();

    session.close();
    return updated;
}
```

But it didn't work correctly... When I try to do update of existed entity with `authorId = 4`:

```
Author author1 = authorDao.updateAuthor(new Author(4, "qweqwe", "qweqwe", "qweqwe", 1000));
```

Get next executed HQL query:

```
Hibernate: update author set age=?, authorId=?, authorName=?, nationality=?, authorSurname=? where id=?
```

and next exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
```

How can I fix this without setting all values separately??

Comment: Just to be double-sure, can you post the `Author` constructor?

Comment: @lealceldeiro, add it to question body

Comment: Are you sure that the id is set on the given author object you try to update? If not then the where clause would say **id = null** and there will not be an row where id is null, so the update query does not affect any row in the table

Comment: Well, here seems that `session.update(author);` definitely  is trying to update based on the `id` property (`0` as it is not set by default) and not taking `authorId` as reference for updating the existing author with the id used to constructor the passed `Author`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

It need just delete `id` property from Author model and paste `@Id` annotation over `authorId` value:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "author")
public class Author {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "authorId", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int authorId;

    @Column(name = "authorName", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "authorSurname")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "nationality")
    private String nationality;

    @Column(name = "age")
    private int age;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Book> bookList;

    public Author(){
    }

    public Author(int authorId, String name, String surname, String nationality, int age) {
        this.authorId = authorId;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.nationality = nationality;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

So now Hibarnate get as `id` exactly `authorId`.
It works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this out 
 yours:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;
```

Replace with this and try

```
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
```